# Full-matrix approach to backpropagation in Artificial Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am learning Artificial Neural Network (ANN) recently and have got a code working and running in Python for the same based on mini-batch training. I followed the book of [Michael Nilson's Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) where there is step by step explanation of each and every algorithm for the beginners. 
There is also a fully working code for handwritten digit recognition which works fine for me too.

However, I am trying to tweak the code a bit by means of passing the whole mini-batch together to train by backpropagation in the matrix form. I have also developed a working code for that, but the code performs real slow when run. Is there any way I can implement a full matrix based approach to mini-batch learning of the network based on back propagation algorithm?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Network:

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes

        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for y, x in zip(sizes[1:], sizes[:-1])]

    def feed_forward(self, a):
        for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w,a) + b)
        return a

    # Calculate the cost derivative (Gradient of C w.r.t. 'a' - Nabla C(a))
    def cost_derivative(self, output_activation, y):
        return (output_activation - y)


    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):

        from scipy.linalg import block_diag 

        n = len(mini_batch)

        xs = [x for x, y in mini_batch]
        features = block_diag(*xs)

        ys = [y for x, y in mini_batch]
        responses = block_diag(*ys)

        ws = [a for a in self.weights for i in xrange(n)]

        new_list = []
        k = 0
        while (k < len(ws)):
            new_list.append(ws[k: k + n])
            k += n

        weights = [block_diag(*elems) for elems in new_list]

        bs = [b for b in self.biases for i in xrange(n)]

        new_list2 = []
        j = 0
        while (j < len(bs)):
            new_list2.append(bs[j : j + n])
            j += n

        biases = [block_diag(*elems) for elems in new_list2]

        baises_dim_1 = [np.dot(np.ones((n*b.shape[0], b.shape[0])), b) for b in self.biases]
        biases_dim_2 = [np.dot(b, np.ones((b.shape[1], n*b.shape[1]))) for b in baises_dim_1]
        weights_dim_1 = [np.dot(np.ones((n*w.shape[0], w.shape[0])), w) for w in self.weights]
        weights_dim_2 = [np.dot(w, np.ones((w.shape[1], n*w.shape[1]))) for w in weights_dim_1]

        nabla_b =  [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in biases_dim_2]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in weights_dim_2]

        delta_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        delta_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]

        zs = []
        activation = features
        activations = [features]

        for w, b in zip(weights, biases):

            z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)

        delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], responses) * sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())

        for l in xrange(2, self.layers):
            z = zs[-l]                                                                      # the weighted input for that layer
            activation_prime = sigmoid_prime(z)                                             # the derivative of activation for the layer
            delta = np.dot(weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * activation_prime           # calculate the adjustment term (delta) for that layer
            nabla_b[-l] = delta                                                             # calculate the bias adjustments - by means of using eq-BP3.
            nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())                  # calculate the weight adjustments - by means of using eq-BP4.

        delta_b = [self.split_cases(b, n) for b in nabla_b]
        delta_w = [self.split_cases(w, n) for w in nabla_w]

        self.weights = [w - (eta/n) * nw for w, nw in zip(self.weights, delta_w)]
        self.biases = [b - (eta/ n) * nb for b, nb in zip(self.biases, delta_b)]



    def split_cases(self, mat, mini_batch_size):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        dim1 = mat.shape[0]/mini_batch_size
        dim2 = mat.shape[1]/mini_batch_size
        sum_samples = np.zeros((dim1, dim2))
        while i < len(mat):

            sum_samples = sum_samples + mat[i: i + dim1, j : j + dim2]
            i += dim1
            j += dim2

        return sum_samples

    """Stochastic Gradient Descent for training in epochs"""
    def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data = None):

        n = len(training_data)

        if test_data:
            n_test = len(test_data)

        for j in xrange(epochs):
            np.random.shuffle(training_data)                                                                    # for each epochs the mini-batches are selected randomly
            mini_batches = [training_data[k: k+mini_batch_size] for k in xrange(0, n, mini_batch_size)]     # select equal sizes of mini-batches for the epochs (last mini_batch size might differ however)

            c = 1

            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                print "Updating mini-batch {0}".format(c)
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
                c += 1
            if test_data:
                print "Epoch {0}: {1}/{2}".format(j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test)

            else:
                print "Epoch {0} completed.".format(j)

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feed_forward(x)), y) for (x, y) in test_data]
        return (sum(int(x == y) for x, y in test_results))

    def export_results(self, test_data):
        results = [(np.argmax(self.feed_forward(x)), y) for (x, y) in test_data]
        k = pd.DataFrame(results)
        k.to_csv('net_results.csv')


# Global functions

## Activation function (sigmoid)
@np.vectorize
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))

## Activation derivative (sigmoid_prime)
@np.vectorize
def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1 - sigmoid(z))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code. The time taken to iterate 30 epochs reduces from 800+ seconds to 200+ seconds on my machine.

As I am new to python, I use what is readily available. This snippet only requires numpy to run.

Give it a try.

```
def feedforward2(self, a):
    zs = []
    activations = [a]

    activation = a
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
        zs.append(z)
        activation = sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)

    return (zs, activations)

def update_mini_batch2(self, mini_batch, eta):
    batch_size = len(mini_batch)

    # transform to (input x batch_size) matrix
    x = np.asarray([_x.ravel() for _x, _y in mini_batch]).transpose()
    # transform to (output x batch_size) matrix
    y = np.asarray([_y.ravel() for _x, _y in mini_batch]).transpose()

    nabla_b, nabla_w = self.backprop2(x, y)
    self.weights = [w - (eta / batch_size) * nw for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b - (eta / batch_size) * nb for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    return

def backprop2(self, x, y):

    nabla_b = [0 for i in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [0 for i in self.weights]

    # feedforward
    zs, activations = self.feedforward2(x)

    # backward pass
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
    nabla_b[-1] = delta.sum(1).reshape([len(delta), 1]) # reshape to (n x 1) matrix
    nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())

    for l in xrange(2, self.num_layers):
        z = zs[-l]
        sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
        delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * sp
        nabla_b[-l] = delta.sum(1).reshape([len(delta), 1]) # reshape to (n x 1) matrix
        nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l - 1].transpose())

    return (nabla_b, nabla_w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original codes from the book, I revised the codes with minor change. The codes are as follows.

```
import random
import numpy as np

class Network(object):

def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                    for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

def feedforward(self, a):
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a) + b)
    return a

def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
        test_data=None):
    training_data = list(training_data)
    n = len(training_data)

    if test_data:
        test_data = list(test_data)
        n_test = len(test_data)

    for j in range(epochs):
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        mini_batches = [
            training_data[k:k + mini_batch_size]
            for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
        if test_data:
            print("Epoch {} : {} / {}".format(j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test))
        else:
            print("Epoch {} complete".format(j))

def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]

    x_matrix_0 = [x for x, y in mini_batch]
    y_matrix_0 = [y for x, y in mini_batch]
    x_matrix = np.concatenate(x_matrix_0, axis=1)
    y_matrix = np.concatenate(y_matrix_0, axis=1)

    nabla_b, nabla_w = self.backprop(x_matrix, y_matrix)

    self.weights = [w - (eta / len(mini_batch)) * nw
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b - (eta / len(mini_batch)) * nb
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

def backprop(self, x, y):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    # feedforward
    activation = x
    activations = [x]  # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
    zs = []  # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation) + np.kron(b, np.ones([1, y.shape[1]]))
        zs.append(z)
        activation = sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)
    # backward pass
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
    nabla_b[-1] = np.reshape([np.sum(nb) for nb in delta], [delta.shape[0], 1])
    for _d, _a in zip(delta.transpose(), activations[-2].transpose()):
        _d = np.reshape(_d, [len(_d), 1])
        _a = np.reshape(_a, [len(_a), 1])
        nabla_w[-1] += np.dot(_d, _a.transpose())

    for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
        z = zs[-l]
        sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
        delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * sp
        nabla_b[-l] = np.reshape([np.sum(nb) for nb in delta], [delta.shape[0], 1])
        for _d, _a in zip(delta.transpose(), activations[-l-1].transpose()):
            _d = np.reshape(_d, [len(_d), 1])
            _a = np.reshape(_a, [len(_a), 1])
            nabla_w[-l] += np.dot(_d, _a.transpose())
    return nabla_b, nabla_w

def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
    return (output_activations - y)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))


def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))
```